# ¿Puedo hacer una lista que contenga funciones?

Tags: python, array, lista, funciones, function

Por ejemplo: 
Tengo tres funciones A,B,C y quiero una lista que contenga A,B,C (arr = [A, B, C]) para después de un tiempo ejecutar la función que contenga por ejemplo: arr en la posición 1 (arr[1]).

```py
    def A():return 0
    def B():return 1
    def C():return 2
    arr=[A(),B(),C()]
    arr[1]
```

y que ejecute la función A.
Es posíble eso en python?

Comment: si se soluciono tu pregunta recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada @ladiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es perfectamente posible. En python todo son objetos, incluidas las funciones, lo que significa que puedes asignarlas a variables, meterlas en listas, en diccionarios, etc. Incluso *pasarlas como parámetro* o *retornarlas como resultado*.

Lo que te falla es la sintaxis.

Por un lado, cuando haces `A()` estás **invocando** la función, y ésta retornará un resultado (0 en este caso) y es ese resultado el que estarías guardando en la lista, en vez de la propia función `A`. Esto se debe a los paréntesis usados tras el nombre, que causan la invocación. Basta eliminar esos paréntesis para tener acceso a "la función en sí". Es decir:

```
arr = [A, B, C]
```

Por otro lado, cuando haces `arr[1]`, estarás accediendo a la función `B` (no A, como decías), pero no la estarás llamando pues faltan los paréntesis al final. Lo que sí funcionará será esto otro:

```
arr[1]()
```

Comment: Gracias, solo puse el ejemplo para saber si era posible pero te agradezco por la aclaración.