# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una función(def) a una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

soy relativamente nuevo usando Python como lenguaje de programación; Hasta ahora me he encontrado con un problema que agradecería mucho al que me ayudase a resolverlo.

```
def ejemplo():    
        
    print("Texto de ejemplo ")

lista = []
```

¿De qué forma podría introducir la función `ejemplo()` en la lista `lista`?.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Puedo hacer una lista que contenga funciones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306127/puedo-hacer-una-lista-que-contenga-funciones)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Puedo hacer una lista que contenga funciones?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/306127/puedo-hacer-una-lista-que-contenga-funciones)

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, no entiendo del todo lo que quieres realizar o necesitas hacer. Pero con lo que comentaste creo que podrían ser de dos formas, te adjunto código comentando las formas:

```
# Primer forma, que te imprima cada letra como elemento de la lista
def ejemplo():
    cadena = "Texto de ejemplo"
    c = list(cadena)
    print(c)

ejemplo()

# segunda forma, que te imprima unicamente tu cadena
def ejemplo2():
    cadena = "Texto de ejemplo"
    lista = [cadena]
    print(lista)

ejemplo2()
```

Asimismo te añado imagen de la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea de ayuda.
¡Saludos!